# No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having an issue mapping a results set of an entity into a POJO.

The Entity uses hibernate resultsetmap from a Tuple and should pass the annotated values into the constructor of the POJO.

**Entity**

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "TaskChangeMapping",
        columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "status", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "data_values", type = String.class)

})
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "ICreateChange.listStartedChangesByInitiator",
      query =
      "SELECT id, status, data_values "
      + "FROM icreate_change "
      + "WHERE initiator = :initiator "
      + "AND workflow_process_id = 0",
      resultSetMapping = "TaskChangeMapping"
    ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
      name = "ICreateChange.listDataValuesAndStatusByChangeId",
      query =
      "SELECT id, status, data_values "
      + "FROM icreate_change "
      + "WHERE id = :changeId",
      resultSetMapping = "TaskChangeMapping"
    )
})

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "icreate_change")
public class ICreateChange {
...
```

This is the POJO class

**ChangeTask**

```
@Data
public class ChangeTask {

  @Getter
  @Value("id")
  private Long id;

  @Getter
  @Value("status")
  private String status;

  @Getter
  @Value("data_values")
  @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
  private String dataValues;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * @param id changeId
   * @param status change status
   * @param dataValues JSON string of data values
   */
  public ChangeTask(
      Long id,
      String status,
      String dataValues
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.status = status;
    this.dataValues = dataValues;
  }
}
```

**Repository**

Note there is no rest controller, its direct to the repository

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/iCreateChange")
public interface ICreateChangeRepository extends JpaRepository<ICreateChange, Long> {

  List<ChangeTask> listDataValuesAndStatusByChangeId(
        @Param("changeId")
        @RequestParam
        @ApiParam(name = "changeId", value = "changeId")
        Long changeId);
}
```

When calling the `listDataValuesAndStatusByChangeId` the following stack trace occurs

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.jlr.ddc.cmpdataapi.model.ChangeTask]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ProjectingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.lambda$and$0(ResultProcessor.java:213) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor$ChainingConverter.convert(ResultProcessor.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.processResult(ResultProcessor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:141) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did find a solution?

Comment: I hit the exact same error, but I wasn't using JPA directly, rather I was using Spring `@Query` annotation with a native query and trying to project into a closed class.  I got the same error. I resolved it by switching to an interface projection instead.